# google places api many filters by type Ex.: restaurant,cafe

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to change the radius category/type filter for a checkbox, so I changed the var type to an array.

ORIGINAL WORKING:

```
var type;
        for (var i = 0; i < document.controls.type.length; i++){
            if (document.controls.type[i].checked){
                type = document.controls.type[i].value;
            }
        }
    startBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
        var search = {
        // keyword: 'comocomo', // not needed with the autocomplete / startBox
        bounds: map.getBounds()
        };
            if (type != 'establishment'){
                search.types = [ type ];
            }
    places.search(search, function(placesArr, status){
```

THE ONE WITH THE ARRAY NOT WORKING: edited:

```
    var type=[];
for (var i = 0; i < document.controls.type.length; i++){
    if (document.controls.type[i].checked){  
        type.push(document.controls.type[i].value)
    }
}
startBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
    var search = {
        bounds: map.getBounds()
    };

var quotedAndCommaSeparated = "'" + type.join("','") + "'";

alert(quotedAndCommaSeparated); // 'establishment','restaurant','lodging'

search.types = [ quotedAndCommaSeparated ];
```

I made many tests, and I don't see what I'm doing wrong. the map doesn't even show.

Comment: What does your HTML look like?  Can you provide a jsfiddle or a link to a map that exhibits the problem?

Comment: I put the original code, in fiddle but didn't manage to make it work, here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sebababi/L922V/ and here the original code: http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/places/keyword_rankBy.html . The changes have to be done in the function called "reallyDoSearch() {"

Comment: [fiddle with map](http://jsfiddle.net/L922V/1/), has a javascript error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null fiddle.jshell.net/L922V/1/show/:172`

Comment: Hi, you couldn't fix it? I updated the fiddle with the Array code, but still doesn't show the markers. new version: http://jsfiddle.net/sebababi/L922V/3/

Comment: I didn't try to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

What's this meant to be, doesn't look like valid Javascript to me:

```
var type[];
```

Should be

```
var type = [];
```

Fix the javascript errors in your code otherwise the map won't show up.

Update:

What you have in quotedAndCommaSeparated is a string like `"'a','b','c'"` that looks a bit like the contents of an array: `['a','b','c']`. But it's not an array, it's just a single string. If you check the length of your search.type array, I'm guessing it equals 1.

What you can do is split your string on the comma to turn it into an array:

```
search.types = quotedAndCommaSeparated.split(",");
```

Comment: Thanks Duncan, that worked great. but still didn't manage to make the filter search for many types. the alert(quotedAndCommaSeparated); // gives: 'establishment','restaurant','lodging' which should be correct. If I force it like this: search.types = [ 'establishment','restaurant','lodging' ]; // it works but not with the variable inside.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a way to turn your string into an array

Comment: Hi Duncan, actually, what I do is to pass the array as a string. So, the length becomes 22 chars. Which I think is correct, because if I put a string like this 'restaurant','lodging' it works. but still didn't manage to make it work. I updated the fiddle which is not working.

Comment: I doubt the places service expects a list like `'a','b'` to be passed to it as a string instead of an array.  I'm not sure what you're up to; `places` is an instance of the `PlacesService` - `places = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);` Then you do `places.search(...)`, but there is no search function on the [PlacesService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlacesService). nearbySearch, radarSearch or textSearch are available though